# Can't type password (or anything else) into plink with svn+ssh

Tags: windows, svn, command-line, ssh, plink

I've been using SVN and Windows for a while now, but recently I tried to get it working on a new machine. I have a svn+ssh:// repository that I need to access but I am unable to because, as I understand it, plink is not hooked up to the console input and thus I cannot type in my password when running svn commands.

[This page](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/05/06/git-ssh-putty-github-unfuddle-the-kitchen-sink.aspx) (near the bottom) also describes the input problem (not with svn specifically though).

I can get around this by using TortoisePlink.exe (which brings up a user/pass input dialog) instead of plink.exe however I'd like to know how to fix the unable-to-type problem with plink. On my Mac I can `svn update` and enter my password without problems; I fail to see why this problem must plague me (and probably others) on Windows. If there is another SSH client that doesn't have this problem then I'd be happy to use that. I know about using public/private keys but I would like a solution that doesn't involve that. Hell, if this is a well known limitation and someone points me to the source I'll try and fix it myself. I want a solution, no matter what it involves, not a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I havent tried this as I work with public/private key system. But here it is.

Install Putty.
Create a profile in it to connect to your SVN server, with the same username and password and same server name as the one in svn+ssh:// url.
Save this profile with same name as the server name in svn+ssh:// url. Note that you will need to save your password here (delete this profile if this method doesnt work)
Now try to connect to svn server, it should either get you to the box straight or prompt for a password that will work.

Public/Private key based method is more secure when you access svn over ssh. Hope you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll fixed (better say - hacked) this issue: you just have to run (onetime) plink with 'auto_store_key_in_cache' option. It will auto-store key in cache and later won't ask you for the key.

Also you can take a look [here](http://www.aspdeveloper.net/tiki-index.php?page=LinuxTipsPuttyNotCachingKeys).